# Performance issue when typing into search input when retrieving objects from store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a search field, which lets the user search books (filters records, which are retrieved with ember-data).

I have found that any access the store from the `results` computed property within my component ([see jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qaxoduko/1/)) makes the typing into the search field very slow (noticeable on my PC, and terrible on smartphone).

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsc8c.jpg) of the Timeline pane when typing a search query. The displayed part show that every keypress causes A LOT of layout (the search field seems to rerendered on every keypress). I also provide the [exported timeline](https://gist.github.com/pedrokost/9295999) which you can load into your dev tools as [explained here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline#saving_and_loading_recordings)

[image: Chrome Timeline showing relayout]

I have tried to recreate the issue in a [jsfiddle](https://gist.github.com/pedrokost/9295999), but it seems to work just fine. The difference might be that in the jsbin I am using fixtures, while in my app I retrieve data from a real API.

I don't understand what is causing this behavior. It may be hard to come to any conclusion from the data I can provide, but does anyone have any ideas? Has anyone experienced similar performance issues?

### Update 2014-03-01

I should note that the performance hit only happens if the `results` computed property contains a call to the store. If I replace it with any other thing (like just returning [], or some random async method -- like $.get) it not display this performance hit.

Additionally, I should make it clear (in case you didn't read the code), that the `results` computed property is not called on every keypress, but only when the search is submitted.

Comment: Just a thought but can you check the network requests tab and see if Ember Data is issuing a new GET request on every key stroke?

Comment: It does not. In fact, the `results` computed property is not called at each keypress (only when enter is pressed). I can't understand how a method that is not called can affect the performance of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Ember/Ember-data bug, but apparently a Google Chrome bug.

I have created a [new question regarding the issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127701/possible-chrome-bug-typing-into-input-field-is-terribly-slow-if-rest-of-page-ha)