# Possible Chrome bug: Typing into input field is terribly slow if rest of page has heavy css

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a page that consists of:

- basic input field
- lots of heavily styled dom elements

Typing in the input field is very slow -- it causes a lot of re-layouting.

[image]

The Timeline tab in the Chrome Dev Tools indicates that only the input field is redrawn. Removing all the heavy CSS makes the typing much faster -- the layout are much shorter.

It makes no sense that:

- the input field triggers a layout when you type in it
- that this layout is dependent on other page elements even if the Inspector only says that the input field is relayouted.

Affected browsers:

- Chrome beta on Linux
- Chrome beta on Android

Not affected:

- Firefox stable/beta on Linux
- Firefox beta on Android

[Here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vuqik/1) that exhibits this problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was that I was forcing this rule in the css of some of the elements on the page:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Removing it made the Layout much faster (unnoticeably short)